Designing the CMOS IC 555
On the basis of following CMOS based schematic of the 555 timer from Wikipedia:
(Image Credit to 
WalterDvorak, 
CC BY 3.0) 


 I designed this simulink model:
[Simulink Model]1
Here the parameters of N-channel MOSFETs are: Rds = 25 m-ohm, Ids = 6 mA, Vth = 1.7 V, Vgs = 10V while of the P-channel ones are: Rds = 167 m-ohm, Ids = -2.5 mA, Vth = -1.4, Vgs = -10V. R4 is 12 K-ohm while the input (Ci) and hold (Ch) capacitance values for the comparators are 10 pF each. However when I simulate the said block in Astable mode, rather than getting a 100Hz square wave (as promised here) I am getting a 4.2V DC output. At this point I am completely hopeless and unable to point the error. Please help me find the mistake I am doing here.


please stop drawing lines through components

For one thing, the mohm channel resistances look like some high-performance discrete parts, not what you get inside a chip. But then you'd need suitably large gate capacitances. You should probably start simulating it in SPICE using either real discrete parts, or using device parameters representative of a CMOS process. CMOS  on-chip mosfets need to have L/d ratio defined, etc. And only once it works in SPICE move it simulink, being careful to validate the performance of simulink models against spice models just to maintain sanity.

Can you replace the schematic images with larger ones? Like, about 3 times larger, or at least twice?

@EdinFifić, well you could open it in new tab it would be automatically enlarged and more detailed. Although I have done it.

@jsotola, okay but how else could I cross-check my model's connections with the given schematic (which infact uses "overhead" lines) in a seemingly complex circuit? Anyways, thx for advice.

@AweKumarJha Normally, the images here are "clickable", in other words they act as a link to the larger image which then pops-up, but it doesn't happen here. Still, the details are fairly small. Regarding the messy lines if you are able to move them, you should be able to make it more presentable, and it will be also easier for you to trace the signals.

Regarding the circuit functionality, the first thing I would recommend is to "build" and simulate it section by section. After you verify each section's functionality, then you can link them and see if and how it all works together. I have actually designed the simplest 555 discrete circuit I could come up with, you can see it here: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/my-own-simplest-discrete-555-timer-design/

@EdinFifić, I really appreciate your help. Shall try the section-wise approach tomorrow. Right now going to sleep. Thank you.

@EdinFifić Thanks for sharing your simple approach to a discrete 555 that one might try and build and perhaps use to understand it better, too. Using a single BJT for each comparator on the voltage divider chain is a reasonable tradeoff for simplicity's sake. To me, a glaring problem is that the output will be "mostly useless," as a great many projects using the 555 timer expect its fairly heavy-load capable 2-quadrant output at pin 3. Do you feel this was/is also an acceptable tradeoff in trying to keep it simple?

In case you need another reference, Hans Camenzind's book "Designing Analog Chips" has a 5V CMOS 555 design with L/U parameters for each transistor, made in a 500nm process. He made it available for free download during his lifetime, should still be so available.

@periblepsis The number one point of my circuit was simplicity and the ability of anyone with the most basic level of understanding of BJT transistors (and the typical access to them) to completely understand the function of the circuit and easily trace the signals through it, as well as very easily build it. At the same time, I have managed to make it function (and have same "pins") as the actual 555, except for the RESET threshold level being different but still made active when connected to ground and inactive or stable when connected to Vcc. Signal tracing was more important than loading.

@periblepsis There are a few ways to buffer the output, one could be the NPN/PNP buffer, but a much better one would be using a P-channel MOSFET with its gate on the -Q output and an N-channel MOSFET with its gate on the Q output, with their drains joined together; that would allow very low output impedance, very fast switching (very short rise and fall times) and rail-to-rail output swing. An ENHANCEMENT of the traditional 555 would be an addition of -Q output, as I and many users have often needed an output opposite of the Q. As I have said before, many improvements can be made to it.

@EdinFifić Thanks for taking a moment. I'm of two minds. The first is to completely embrace your arrangement as a very good teaching stair-step. The output is essentially useless faced with the usual "google-search" for 555 timer circuits. It mostly won't work due to the poor quality "pin 3 output" design. But I have to admit that it is a very good segue if the goal is strictly about taking a small step towards larger teaching goals. The other mind I have is that many will still need the high current compliance 2-quadrant output and it fails there. But thanks! I do take your point.

@periblepsis And it is because of suggestions like yours that I had posted here for suggestions or even fewer parts needed (if possible), but some people felt like it shouldn't be here on SE. I would have fine-tuned it until it was good for an all-around, generic purpose use as well. I agree that the output part is really not there, merely a hookup into the SR latch. Here is the link to my closed and deleted post on it (I don't know if you can see it): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/724917/constructive-input-welcome-simplest-discrete-transistor-based-555-timer-design
